# Why does it show my boyfriend as active all the time on Messenger,when I know for sure he's not?

Tags: facebook-messenger

I've. Noticed my BFs active Messenger status is on continually.Rarely does it show when he was last active like mine does.He has been asleep next to me for hours and his Messenger active status never went inactive...can someone please explain?

Comment: Please share what web browser or app you and your boyfriend use for Messenger and if possible the privacy settings.